# Events loaded two times

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

In a page I have two same HTML form one is generated dynamically through jquery and one is through `asp.net`. I have added validation on click  button of each of the same pages.

First button

```
var s = $(' <input type="button" ID="btnFrmSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit"  value="FrmSubmit" />');
$("#mainTbl").after(s);
```

Second button

Which is inside `</asp:Panel>`

```
<input name="btnFrmSubmitn" type="button" id="btnFrmSubmitn" runat="server"  value="Submitn"/>
```

First jquery form start with

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on("click", "[id*=btnFrmSubmit]", function () {
        alert("hi");  
        //validation Part
        alert("v1");  
    });
});
```

Second jquery form start with

```
$(function () {  
    $("#btnFrmSubmitn").click(function () {
        alert("hi...");  
        //validation Part
        alert("V2");  
    });
});
```

Issue is on if I click second submit button `btnFrmSubmitn`
Then following sequence occur

```
1) alert("hi...");
2) alert("V2");
3) alert("hi");
4) alert("v1");
```

`3)` and `4)` sequence shouldn’t occur any idea would be appreciated to solve this issue.

Comment: That's because `btnFrmSubmitn` contains `btnFrmSubmit`, which makes the first event handler also gets attached. So basically, you've attached 2 event handlers for `btnFrmSubmitn`. And that works as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line here:

```
$(document).on("click", "[id*=btnFrmSubmit]", function () {
```

selects all elements which have an ID that includes the string `'btnFrmSubmit'` anywhere in their ID. If you want that to only apply to the first button, then select that button's ID exactly, without the `*`:

```
$(document).on("click", "[id=btnFrmSubmit]", function () {
```

or, more concisely

```
$(document).on("click", "#btnFrmSubmit", function () {
```